# Why  jquery mobile styles not loading on xcode simulator build using phone gap?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, xcode3.2

[image]I've implemented a simple app using a listview From jQuery-mobile, it appears as hyperlink on the iphone simulator & device. It works fine on android.

[image]
    
    
    
    PhoneGap

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script> 


     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>My Title</h1>


</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <p>Hello world</p>      
<!-- /content -->
<form>
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star">Star button</a>
</form</div>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="false">
<li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Some source code would help troubleshooting, how does the code for your view look?

Comment: hi, i am not able to put html code. i used <div data-role="content"> 
  <p>Hello world</p>  
<form>
   <label for="slider-0">Input slider:</label>
   <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider-0" value="25" min="0" max="100"  />
</form</div>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
 <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
</div>where in iphone listview apear as list of hyperlink and slider as textfield.I linked jquerymobile css and .js in header

Comment: <head>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>                                                     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>My Title</h1> 
</div>
<div data-role="content">  
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="false">
 <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

Comment: sorry but i dont knw how to format code in comment.

Comment: Instead of inserting your code as a **comment**, edit your **question** and insert the code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need add `code.jquery.com` to `ExternalHosts` in `PhoneGap.plist`, if you link online jquery mobile file to your html file.